# NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/api/OffsetRequest for Storm jar

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, sbt, apache-storm

I am trying to submit Storm topology to the cluster but I constantly get the same error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/api/OffsetRequest
    at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.java:48)
    at org.apache.storm.kafka.trident.TridentKafkaConfig.<init>(TridentKafkaConfig.java:30)
    at storm.StormStreaming$.main(StormStreaming.scala:41)
    at storm.StormStreaming.main(StormStreaming.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.api.OffsetRequest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

I submit jar file using

```
./storm jar /patht/storm-app.jar storm.StormStreaming
```

How can it be fixed? I tried aligning resources versions - Kafka and Storm - but it does not seem to work.
My build.sbt file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
val sparkVersion = "2.4.4"
val flinkVersion = "1.9.1"
val stormVersion = "2.1.0"
val kafkaVersion = "2.4.0"
    dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.6"
    dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.6"
    dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.9.6"

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % kafkaVersion excludeAll(
        ExclusionRule("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"),
        ExclusionRule("log4j", "log4j"),
        ExclusionRule("org.apache.zookeeper", "zookeeper")
        ),
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion excludeAll("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"),
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion excludeAll("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"),
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
      "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.3",
      "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "4.0.7",
      "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-stream" % "4.0.7",
      "org.apache.flink" % "flink-core" % flinkVersion % "provided",
      "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion excludeAll("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"),
      "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion excludeAll("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"),
      "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % flinkVersion excludeAll("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"),
      "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-kafka" % flinkVersion,
      "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-runtime-web" % flinkVersion,
      "org.apache.flink" % "flink-avro-confluent-registry" % flinkVersion,
      "org.apache.storm" % "storm-core" % stormVersion % "provided" excludeAll(
        ExclusionRule("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"),
        ExclusionRule("org.slf4j", "log4j-over-slf4j")
        ),
      "org.apache.storm" % "storm-kafka-client" % stormVersion excludeAll("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"),
      "org.apache.storm" % "storm-sql-core" % stormVersion excludeAll("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"),
      "org.apache.storm" % "storm-sql-runtime" % stormVersion excludeAll("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12"),
      "org.apache.storm" % "storm-kafka" % "1.2.3" excludeAll("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")
    )
```

Comment: Why do you need Spark & Flink libraries in a Storm job? Those should almost never be mixed anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong Kafka jar. You should depend on `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients` instead of `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.xx`, which is the Kafka server side jar.

The dependence on `kafka/api/OffsetRequest` is coming from `storm-kafka`, which should not be used. It's using an old Kafka client API which is no longer present in Kafka. Use `storm-kafka-client` instead.

Comment: AFAIK, `kafka/api/OffsetRequest` isn't part of `kafka-clients`

Comment: You are right, will correct my answer. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: [`storm-kafka` isn't right either](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.10.2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/api/OffsetRequest.scala)

Comment: Yes it is, but I could have been more explicit. `storm-kafka` uses the client library in `org.apache.kafka:kafka`, which has been removed from Kafka as of I think 2.0.0. The OffsetRequest class is part of this client library. The reason for the NoClassDefFound is that the OP is using a part of `storm-kafka` that depends on this removed client library.

Comment: Removing storm-kafka and kafka dependencies helped